# can not read and save entity when test on junit with jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit

Hello im currently writing test code on concurrency test and have some problem with it

before show my code my dependency is like it

1. h2
2. spring boot 3.2
3. jpa
4. junit 5
5. redisson 3.22.1

so it is test logic that generate some key value in good order .

and i have some problem that in code , when i put breakpoint and check "all" in below .
it's count is zero and all test goes fail.

and the wierd thing is that sometimes it is good and test pass

so im really need help to why it is happen .

```
    void readyDocument() {
        var article = monkey.giveMeBuilder(TranslationArticleEntity.class)
                .set("articleId", ARTICLE_ID)
                .set("title", INITIAL_TITLE)
                .set("authorId", USER_ID)
                .set("techTags", Set.of(TechTag.JAVA))
                .sample();
        translationArticleRepository.saveAndFlush(article);

        var versionContent = monkey.giveMeBuilder(TranslationArticleVersionContentEntity.class)
                .set("versionContentId", 0L)
                .set("articleId", ARTICLE_ID)
                .set("version", INITIAL_VERSION)
                .set("editorId", USER_ID)
                .set("content", INITIAL_CONTENT)
                .sample();
        versionContentRepository.saveAndFlush(versionContent);


        var all = translationArticleRepository.findAll();

        log.info("For test 1");
        // For test 1
    }
```

and this is all my test code

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("local")
@Slf4j
public class TranslationUpdateIT {
    @Autowired
    private TranslationArticleUpdateService updateService;

    @Autowired
    private TranslationArticleVersionContentEntityRepository versionContentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TranslationArticleEntityRepository translationArticleRepository;

    private final Long USER_ID = 1L;

    private final Long ARTICLE_ID = 1L;

    private final Long INITIAL_VERSION = 1L;

    private final String INITIAL_TITLE = "TITLE";

    private final String INITIAL_CONTENT = "CONETENT";

    private final int ITERATION = 1000;

    static final FixtureMonkey monkey = FixtureMonkey.builder()
            .objectIntrospector(FieldReflectionArbitraryIntrospector.INSTANCE)
            .build();

    @Test
    void 비동기_update_id_1000회_시도() throws InterruptedException {
        // Given
        readyDocument();

        // For test 2
        var all = translationArticleRepository.findAll();

        // When
        asyncUpdateAndWait(ITERATION);

        // Then
        // iteration 횟수만큼 버전이 생겼는지 확인 .
        checkVersions(ITERATION);

    }

    private void checkVersions(int iteration) {
        List<TranslationArticleVersionContentEntity>
                versionContents = versionContentRepository.findAll();

        Set<Long> versions = new HashSet<>();

        versionContents.stream()
                .forEach(e -> {
                    if (e.getArticleId() == ARTICLE_ID)
                        versions.add(e.getVersion());
                });

        assertEquals(ITERATION + 1, versions.size());
        assertEquals(ITERATION + INITIAL_VERSION, versions.stream().mapToInt(x -> x.intValue()).max().getAsInt());
        assertEquals(INITIAL_VERSION, versions.stream().mapToInt(x -> x.intValue()).min().getAsInt());
    }

    private void asyncUpdateAndWait(int iter) {

        // For test 3
        var all = translationArticleRepository.findAll();

        List<CompletableFuture<Boolean>> completableFutureList =
                IntStream.range(0, ITERATION)
                        .mapToObj(e -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                            updateService.update(
                                    new TranslationArticleUpdateRequest(
                                            ARTICLE_ID,
                                            INITIAL_VERSION,
                                            String.valueOf(e) + "content"
                                    ), USER_ID
                            );
                            log.info("{}th update ", e);
                            return Boolean.TRUE;
                        }).exceptionally(ex -> {
                            log.error("Error during update operation", ex);
                            return Boolean.FALSE; // 실패한 경우 false 반환
                        }))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        CompletableFuture<Void> allOf = CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[ITERATION]));

        log.info("Wait until all future close");
        // 모든 요청이 종료될때까지 대기.
        allOf.join();


        log.info("All future joined");

    }

    void readyDocument() {
        var article = monkey.giveMeBuilder(TranslationArticleEntity.class)
                .set("articleId", ARTICLE_ID)
                .set("title", INITIAL_TITLE)
                .set("authorId", USER_ID)
                .set("techTags", Set.of(TechTag.JAVA))
                .sample();
        translationArticleRepository.saveAndFlush(article);

        var versionContent = monkey.giveMeBuilder(TranslationArticleVersionContentEntity.class)
                .set("versionContentId", 0L)
                .set("articleId", ARTICLE_ID)
                .set("version", INITIAL_VERSION)
                .set("editorId", USER_ID)
                .set("content", INITIAL_CONTENT)
                .sample();
        versionContentRepository.saveAndFlush(versionContent);


        var all = translationArticleRepository.findAll();

        log.info("For test 1");
        // For test 1
    }

}
```

help me let me know why the entity is not saved or why i can not query it with "findAll" method